# BusyBox : dhcp client seems to cause NFS mount to stop working

Tags: linux, nfs, dhcp, busybox

I have a BusyBox based embedded Linux system, mounting the RFS via NFS.  This works fine except when I try to use udhcpd to get a DHCP address for eth0.  This then causes the NFS mount to stop working.  Any ideas as to what's going on?

/etc/network/interfaces is:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

And the problem I see at bootup time is:

```
udhcpc (v1.20.2) started
Sending discover...
Sending select for 10.140.9.57...
Lease of 10.140.9.57 obtained, lease time 86400

nfs: server 10.140.9.137 not responding, still trying
```

Comment: if you mounted the NFS partition, it must be that you had an ip address (which had been retrieved, I guess, by your pxe client, and, I also guess, through dhcp). Why do you want to refresh the ip address then?

Comment: Yes, the system seems to be getting an IP address by some means prior to udhcpc running.  But for production we'll need udhcpc working, and I'd like it to work while still testing things mounted via NFS.

Comment: Do you have another NIC on the machine?

Comment: Yes, eth0 and eth1, but I am not using eth1.

Comment: As for testing dhcp you should use your other interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use eth1 to try your dhcp server.

If you wish to keep your NFS mount while you're changing your IP address on eth0, I suggest you set up an *alias* on your interface, to try your dhcp server.

Keep in mind that you need to keep a TCP/IP connection to your NFS server if you want to keep the mount up. Another solution would be to specify a very long timeout in your `exports` file (option `timeo=x`, in tenths of a second).

Write the following in your /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
# put your network information here
  address x.X.x.x
  netmask x.x.x.x
  gateway x.x.x.x

auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet dhcp
```

Comment: I tried adding a long timeo of 900 to the Linux boot args, but that didn't seem to fix things.  I'll try eth1 when I get it wired up tomorrow.  What does the eth0:1 syntax specify exactly?

Comment: eth0:1 means that you declare using an alias for interface eth0, with the id #1. It is basically a way to create a virtual interface, and assign it an independent ip address.

Comment: Also just tried the virtual interface technique you mentioned in the file above, it's working nicely.  Thanks, you saved me quite a lot of time :)

Comment: glad it worked!